# How to Know if a Plugin can be used with my Theme

Tags: plugins, themes

I am new to wordpress & I am using a paid theme on my site [www.freelancepulp.com](http://www.freelancepulp.com)

I want to know how I can identify if a plugin is good suit for my theme or not? I had to remove all the plugins on my site because it crashed the theme & I was not able to go into Admin panel last night....

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

So *in theory* WordPress extensions are all using its APIs to peacefully and happily coexist.

In practice the landscape of WordPress extensions is a brutal mess, with literally tens of thousands of them, produced by developers of drastically different qualification.

The two basic practices to mitigate and save your sanity:

1. If you are in a planning stages and plan to use paid products, inquire with their developers for possible issues. It's pretty valid pre–sale question, and for popular things they should typically be aware if anything is a problematic combination.
2. Have a separate copy of site for testing. Typical practice among developers is to have a local site, more involved projects tend to also have dedicated staging servers. Even for relatively basic/personal site nothing should really be going into production right away, without being tried out in testing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no simple formula to determine if a specific plugin and theme will work together. There is no testing body that mixes all possible combinations together to verify the work; there are too many themes and plugins for such a solution to be viable.

This leaves the ownership of the task in the hands of those that are trying to install the pieces together.  Since you have a paid theme it presumably means you have support for that theme.  If you haven't already, contact the theme maker with your issue for assistance. If it broke all plugins, chances are there is a problem in the theme. You could also go to the support pages for the plugins to post a question about the compatibility problem you see.

One thing to try before going for help though is to confirm which plugins are broken.  I assume first that they work without your new theme.  Enable the new theme and then start turning them on one by one with the new theme and test. When one breaks, make note, disable and try another of your plugins. Once you have your list, contact the theme builder and plugin developers for more assistance in resolving the conflict.